# ¿Cómo hacer para hacer una operación cuando se da enter?

Tags: java, netbeans

Quiero hacer que cuando el usuario de clic en la tecla `ENTER`, se resuelva una operación.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

     if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
         int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt_num1.getText());
         int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt_num2.getText());
         int res = num1+num2;
         lbl_resultados.setText(res+"");
     }
 }
```

Tengo ese código según yo para obtener el evento del `ENTER`

Pero como lo utilizo? Alguna idea?

Comment: Estas programando para consola, o para GUI por ejemplo swing?

Comment: Estoy para GUI, pero no con Drag and Drop, por medio de código estructirado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar un [EventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) mediante el cual puedes capturar las teclas presionadas, en el caso que requieres puedes detectar al dar clic en la tecla "ENTER" para de esta forma realizar la operación, te doy el ejemplo, basado en tu código original, al dar clic en un botón:

```
 Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Pulsa una tecla.");                      
        btn.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + e.getCode());     
                 switch(e.getCode()){
                       case ENTER:{                
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt_num1.getText());
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt_num2.getText());
                        int res = num1+num2;
                        lbl_resultados.setText(String.valueOf(res));
                       }
                }
            }            
        });
```